# How to display all the number in a list after addition?

Tags: python

I have a list of some lists of numbers where I have to add up everything and print it out this way:

```
5+6+7 = 18
```

I can print the sum of each list, but how can I print out 5+6+7, 1+2+3+8+4, etc.?

```
mylist= [[5,6,7],[1,2,3,8,4],[1,2],[6,7,8,10,12]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```py
mylist= [[5,6,7],[1,2,3,8,4],[1,2],[6,7,8,10,12]]
print(','.join(['+'.join(map(str,alist)) for alist in mylist]))
```

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
mylist= [[5,6,7],[1,2,3,8,4],[1,2],[6,7,8,10,12]]

output = ''
for l in mylist:
    for i in l:
        if i != l[-1]:
            output = output + f'{i}+'
        else:
            output = output + f'{i},' 

output = output[:-1] #removes final comma
print(output)
```

Let me know if you want further commentary on what each line is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist= [[5,6,7],[1,2,3,8,4],[1,2],[6,7,8,10,12]]


for ls in mylist: 
    sum = 0
    print_str = ""
    for item in ls:
        sum+=item
        print_str += str(item)+'+'
    print(f"{print_str[:-1]} = {sum}")    # [:-1] means everything except the last character
```

Output:

```
5+6+7 = 18
1+2+3+8+4 = 18
1+2 = 3
6+7+8+10+12 = 43
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be to flat the 2-D list into a single one

```
flat = [str(item) for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]
print("+".join(flat) + "= ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist= [[5,6,7],[1,2,3,8,4],[1,2],[6,7,8,10,12]]

# if you need a object (list) containing the sums
result=[sum(sublist) for sublist in mylist] 

# if you need strings to be printed out as requested:
result_strs=[str(sublist).replace(', ','+')[1:-1]+' = '+str(sum(sublist)) for sublist in mylist]
print('\n'.join(result_strs))
```